# Android - Interchange sounds through timer

Tags: android

I have a button that is linked to a timer where it plays a given sound every 500ms. This is working as intended, but I want it to play a different sound on **every 4th loop:**

> *sound1 sound1 sound1* **sound2** *sound1 sound1 sound1* **sound2** etc..

Does anyone know the right way about doing this?

```
final MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snd1);
final MediaPlayer sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snd2);

Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Timer timer = new Timer("click", true);
        TimerTask tone = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                sound1.start();
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tone, 500, 500);
    }
 });
```

Comment: In your loop, if the counter is dividable by 4, play sound 2. Else play sound 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
final MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snd1);
final MediaPlayer sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snd2);
int sound = 1;
Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Timer timer = new Timer("click", true);
        TimerTask tone = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                if (sound % 4 != 0){
                sound1.start();
                sound += 1;
                }else{
                sound2.start();
                sound = 1;
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tone, 500, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your thread:

```
if(count / 4 == 1){
    playSound2();
    count = 1;
}else{
    playSound1();
    count++;
}
```

count is a variable you declare in your class:

```
int count = 1;
```

And when you need to stop, make sure you reset `count`.